# What am I missing to exclude uninteresting words from my wordcloud?

Tags: python-3.x

```
   def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
    
    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
    dict = {}
    new_list = []
    for word in file_contents.lower().split():
        if word.isalpha not in uninteresting_words:
            new_list.append(word)
    
    for word in new_list:
        if word not in dict.keys():
            dict[word] = new_list.count(word)

    
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(dict)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

I have fixed my code so it doesn't return any Errors except it is still returning a word cloud with uninteresting words in it. I feel `if word.isalpha not in uninteresting_words:` should take care of it assuming everything else is correct.

Comment: do you maybe mean `if word.isalpha() and word not in uninteresting_words`? because right now what your code does is check if the function `word.isalpha` is in `uninteresting_words`, which it never is

Comment: Ok yeah that one looks better. I forgot the () after the string method and also to include an ```and``` statement, I guess I thought that combining it like ``` if word.isalpha() not in uninteresting_words:``` was possible